# Check OpenGL implementation via Make and/or Qmake?

Tags: opengl, makefile, implementation, qmake

I'd like to know if it's possible to get the OpenGL implementation (e.g., Mesa, Nvidia, AMD, etc.) so I can set (or not set) a define macro in my project's source automatically via QMake (ideally) or a Makefile. Note that I'm not using the Qt Libraries for this, just their IDE and build system.

An example from my project file:

```
DEFINES += USE_GL_CORE
```

This works great for my desktop tower, because then I can use GLSL 3.3 or just about any current version of OpenGL for that matter, since I have a decent Nvidia card. On my laptop, however, I'm running the i5-2410M Sandy Bridge, which only supports up to OpenGL 3.1 on the GPU. While i can just as well comment out the macro before a build and anytime I pull from the repo to my laptop, it would be nice to automate the process.

Thus, I was hoping to see if it's possible to query such a thing via *nix, and if possible, Windows as well.

Comment: Unless you're going to force your users to build the code themselves, this probably isn't a good idea. Where the code gets built and where it gets *executed* may not be the same place.

Comment: What would you suggest as an alternative?